# How to make "pandoc" use a specific font when converting a plaintext file to PDF?

Tags: pdf, pandoc, plaintext, fixed-width

After a *lot* of trouble, I was finally able to run the command without errors:

```
pandoc -i 1.txt -o 1.pdf
```

The result is a PDF with completely messed up text because it uses some other font than Courier[ New]. Some varying-width, default font.

After reading and searching for a long time, I found this: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf

The option "fontfamily" is mentioned, so I tried to do:

```
pandoc -i 1.txt -o 1.pdf --fontfamily=Courier
```

However, this results in:

```
Unknown option --fontfamily.
Try pandoc --help for more information.
```

I have looked through the entire "pandoc --help" output without finding any mention of fonts.

How do I set the font to be used?

(I'm trying my very best to not also add: "and why is it so incredibly difficult/cryptic/undocumented to do the most basic imaginable thing?"...)

I'm not even sure that this will fix all the problems. I just assume that the document is all messed up because the font isn't using fixed-width letters.

Comment: see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#fonts or to set it on the command-line: `pandoc -V fontfamily=Courier`

Comment: indeed, LaTeX can sometimes be a bit of a pain... you can try the other `--pdf-engine`s supported by pandoc... but each one has its own quirks ;-)